# RTSP-сервер

Tags: сервер

Что такое RTSP-сервер? Как его настроить?

Comment: Вопрос неполон. Не хватает ещё вопроса "зачем?".

Comment: Вопрос не полный. На какой системе хотите поднять? Для какой цели? Такие вопросы задают в поисковике, а не на таком портале как этот.

Answer (score 1):

Материал из Википедии — свободной энциклопедии
Потоковый протокол реального времени (Real Time Streaming Protocol, RTSP), разработанный IETF в 1998 году и описанный в RFC 2326, является прикладным протоколом, предназначенным для использования в системах, работающих с мультимедиа данными, и позволяющий клиенту удалённо управлять потоком данных с сервера, предоставляя возможность выполнения команд, таких как «Старт», «Стоп», а также доступа по времени к файлам, расположенным на сервере.
RTSP не выполняет сжатие, а также не определяет метод инкапсуляции мультимедийных данных и транспортные протоколы. Передача потоковых данных сама по себе не является частью протокола RTSP. Большинство серверов RTSP используют для этого стандартный транспортный протокол реального времени, осуществляющий передачу аудио- и видеоданных.

так чисто посмеяться. неужели сложно найти в нете первые 2-3 ссылки?